# Set a radio button in an ng-repeat to checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Evening all. Could anyone tell me how to set a radio button to checked in an ng-repeat when it loads? In the table below I have a list of prices with a sort function I created. It sorts from the lowest price down. Is there a way I can set the lowest price radio button to 'checked' each time the table loads?

```
<table> 
<tr ng-repeat="prices in productVariant.prices | orderBy: tcoSort">
    <td><strong>{{prices.code }}</strong></td>
    <td ng-click="displayFullPricing(prices)">
            <input type="radio"  name="{{variant.code}}" ng-click="displayFullPricing(prices, $index)">
        </td>
</tr>
```

```
$scope.tcoSort = function (productVariant) {
return  productVariant.nonRecurring.retailPrice + (productVariant.monthly.retailPrice * $scope.productAttributesObj.Term);
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple used $scope.modelName and set its value to any of the value(attribute) of radio button you want to set by default for example:-

Male
Female

now set $scope.one="male" in controller you will get the default value to radio button.

In case of ng-repeat concept is same but you just need to use $parent with the model of ng-repeat because ng-repeat creates its own scope that can not be accessed from controller.

Below is small simulated example:-

```
 <div ng-repeat="check in people">
                <input type="radio" name="hello" value="{{check.name}}" ng-model="$parent.human"/> {{check.name}}
                </div>

 $scope.people=[
        { 
            'name':'rachit'
        },
        { 
            'name':'gulati'
        },
        { 
            'name':'rocks'
        }
    ]
    $scope.human='gulati';//You need to set it to the lowest price from your array .
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky10k43g/)

Comment: Ah I see I was missing the ng-model

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio"  name="{{variant.code}}" ng-click="displayFullPricing(prices, $index)" checked>
```

??

Comment: Ah, I understand... didn't really catch the ng-repeat directive, I see why this wouldn't work now...

Answer (score 0):

An example using checkboxes that you could use:

```
<tr ng-repeat="content in contents" ng-class="{danger: currentContent.resource_uri === content.resource_uri || checkboxes.isSelected[content.id]}"  name="content[{{$index}}]" ng-click="selectContent(content, $index);">
      <td class="grid-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.isSelected[content.id]" name="checkbox[{{content.id}}]" ng-checked="checkboxes.isSelected[content.id]" ng-change="changeCheckbox(content, $index)"/></td></tr>
```

this is a snippet from my code I guess what you need is

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.isSelected[content.id]" name="checkbox[{{content.id}}]" ng-checked="checkboxes.isSelected[content.id]" ng-change="changeCheckbox(content, $index)"/>
```

hope it helps